# .NET CF : Scrolling Issue (SB_TOP does not work)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-mobile-6.5

**(.NET CF/Windows Mobile 6.5)** I have a panel which contains some controls. I am using the below pInvoke to set the panel's scroll bar  to the Top, with the page scrolled all the way up.

```
 private static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, int wParam, IntPtr lParam);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]

 SendMessage(this.tabPanel.Handle, WM_VSCROLL,6, new IntPtr(0));
```

The above line does not work in CF.

While the below ones are working

```
 SendMessage(this.tabPanel.Handle, WM_VSCROLL,2, new IntPtr(0));// page up
 SendMessage(this.tabPanel.Handle, WM_VSCROLL,3, new IntPtr(0));//page down
```

Issue is When I pass one of these values(6 or 7). 6 and 7 corresponds to

```
SB_TOP          = 6,
SB_LEFT         = 6,
SB_BOTTOM       = 7,
SB_RIGHT        = 7,
```

Any help on this,please?

Comment: After SendMessage, try 'this.tabPanel.Refresh()', works for me using a TextBox.